# uninstall python on mac Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, uninstallation

I'm a new Mac user. I installed python 2.7.6 but I cannot run my scripts (through IDLE or simply a script). I want to reinstall it but I don't want to mess with the version which comes pre-installed on mac.
Thank you for your help.
note: there are questions on stackOverflow that are similar to mine, yet they do not address the issue of the pre-installed version of python. or is it irrelevant?

Comment: Installed how? From where?

Comment: Hi! I downloaded it from python.org and ran it from there. I did not use the terminal to install it if that's what you mean.

Comment: So, first link in the table on http://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-335/?

Comment: yes, it's the first link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To uninstall python, see: [How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4)

A potential solution would be to specify which python interpreter to use when writing your scripts. Or you can specify a python alias, store which python interpreter you wish to use and save it to your .bash_profile.

This might also guide you to the right direction: 
[Setting default interpreter for a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374307/setting-default-interpreter-for-a-python-script)